# How I can access the terms of policy on a website to see if I can scrape information needed for analysis

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape information on a website using selenium and when I go through the Chrom Web Driver the item I am trying to scrape will say "item is not available" when I am trying to get the information.

Is there a way I can see the terms of policy for a website?
If I am able to scrape this information, do I have to implement something else in my code to wait for the information to load properly?

I have tried using Web Driver Wait to access the information properly and it is giving me errors saying that it is not accessible.

Comment: The first part of your question - _How I can access the terms of policy on a website to see if I can scrape_ is not about programming and thus not suitable for SO. The second part is so vague and lacks any detail - i.e. your code, what site you try to scrape, etc. that it's not possible to answer

Comment: Check [help/on-topic] and [ask]